# Parse xml and write a csv with header columns

Tags: python, xml, csv, qgis

I am trying to parse an xml file containing meteo data and to write some value in a csv file.
I'm not sure that this code is elegant but it works.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# url of xml to parse
baseUrl = ('http://www.arpa.veneto.it/bollettini/meteo/h24/img08/0144.xml')
resp = requests.get(baseUrl)
msg = resp.content
tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
for stazione in tree.iter('STAZIONE'):
    idstaz= stazione.find('IDSTAZ').text
    for sensore in stazione.iter('SENSORE'):
      id= sensore.find('ID').text  
      for dati in sensore.iter('DATI'):
        ist = dati.get('ISTANTE') 
        vm = dati.find('VM').text
        f = open('D:/GIS/_Temp/result.csv', 'a')
        print >> f, idstaz, id, ist, vm
        f.close()
```

I'm not sure that this code is elegant but it works.

```
144 300000864 201701080100 -4.2
144 300000864 201701080200 -4.5
144 300000864 201701080300 -4.8
144 300000864 201701080400 -5.5
...
```

but I don't know how to add the headers to the columns.

Comment: @Mort. Thanks for revision

Answer (score 1):

Open the file before the for loop and add header to file

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# url of xml to parse
baseUrl = ('http://www.arpa.veneto.it/bollettini/meteo/h24/img08/0144.xml')
resp = requests.get(baseUrl)
msg = resp.content
tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
f = open('D:/GIS/_Temp/result.cvs', 'a')
f.write('STAZIONE,IDSTAZ,SENSORE,ISTANTE')
for stazione in tree.iter('STAZIONE'):
    idstaz= stazione.find('IDSTAZ').text
    for sensore in stazione.iter('SENSORE'):
      id= sensore.find('ID').text  
      for dati in sensore.iter('DATI'):
        ist = dati.get('ISTANTE') 
        vm = dati.find('VM').text

        print >> f, idstaz, id, ist, vm

f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Shijo. I have changed a little bit your code to have a right tab `f.write('STAZIONE IDSTAZ SENSORE ISTANTE\n')`